# How to get rid of serverless "Warning: Invalid configuration encountered at root: unrecognized property 'deploymentBucket'"

Tags: aws-lambda, config, serverless, serverless-framework, compiler-warnings

I've got a web application running on the serverless framework version 3.7.5. Every time I deploy my lambda function I get this warning:

"Warning: Invalid configuration encountered at root: unrecognised property 'deploymentBucket'".

I have attached the "serverless.yml" file below for external scrutiny. Is my configuration of the "deploymentBucket" property not valid? Do I need to change or edit any of the properties?

Note: Deployment works fine as it's simply a warning and I am able to proceed to testing my api endpoints... I just find this warning a tad bothersome and would like to erase it once and for all. Thanks in advance!

Here's my serverless.yml file

```yaml
# Welcome to Serverless!
#
# This file is the main config file for your service.
# It's very minimal at this point and uses default values.
# You can always add more config options for more control.
# We've included some commented out config examples here.
# Just uncomment any of them to get that config option.
#
# For full config options, check the docs:
#    docs.serverless.com
#
# Happy Coding!

service: poppy-seed
# app and org for use with dashboard.serverless.com
#app: your-app-name
#org: your-org-name

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
frameworkVersion: '3.7.5'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java11
  timeout: 30
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

# you can overwrite defaults here
#  stage: dev
#  region: us-east-1
    variable1: value1

# you can add packaging information here
package:
  artifact: build/libs/poppy-seed-dev-all.jar

functions:
  poppy-seed:
    handler: com.serverless.lambda.Handler
#    The following are a few example events you can configure
#    NOTE: Please make sure to change your handler code to work with those events
#    Check the event documentation for details
    events:
      - http:
          path: "{proxy+}"
          method: ANY
          cors: true


deploymentBucket:
  blockPublicAccess: true # Prevents public access via ACLs or bucket policies. Default is false
  skipPolicySetup: false # Prevents creation of default bucket policy when framework creates the deployment bucket. Default is false
  name: # Deployment bucket name. Default is generated by the framework
  maxPreviousDeploymentArtifacts: 5 # On every deployment the framework prunes the bucket to remove artifacts older than this limit. The default is 5
  versioning: false # enable bucket versioning. Default is false
  deploymentPrefix: serverless # The S3 prefix under which deployed artifacts should be stored. Default is serverless
  disableDefaultOutputExportNames: false # optional, if set to 'true', disables default behavior of generating export names for CloudFormation outputs
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221 # optional, version of hashing algorithm that should be used by the framework


plugins:
  - serverless-sam
#  Resources:
#    NewResource:
#      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
#      Properties:
#        BucketName: my-new-bucket
#  Outputs:
#     NewOutput:
#       Description: "Description for the output"
#       Value: "Some output value"
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that the `deploymentBucket` property is not recognized and as such it is not doing what you think it should be doing.

According to [serverless docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml), `deploymentBucket` should be a property under `provider` not a root property.

Comment: Hi @NoelLlevares. Thank you so much for your response. I did as the docs suggested and moved the `deploymentBucket` property under `provider` which cleared the warning

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of this warning by moving the `deploymentBucket` property under `provider` instead of registering it as a root property. The modified serverless.yml file is attached below:

```
service: poppy-seed

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java11
  timeout: 30
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221 
  deploymentBucket:
    blockPublicAccess: true 
    skipPolicySetup: false 
    name: poppy-seed
    maxPreviousDeploymentArtifacts: 5
    versioning: false # enable bucket versioning. Default is false


package:
  artifact: build/libs/poppy-seed-dev-all.jar

functions:
  poppy-seed:
    handler: com.serverless.lambda.Handler


events:
  - http:
      path: "{proxy+}"
      method: ANY
      cors: true

plugins:
  - serverless-sam
```

Also read up the [serverless documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml) for more clarity. Thanks again to @NoelLlevares for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to update to latest version of serverless in my case some keys were unrecognized in old version